# How to stack number of rows to one row and assign id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe likes this:

```
band    mean    raster
1   894.343482  D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170219_095504.tif
2   1159.282304 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170219_095504.tif
3   1342.291595 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170219_095504.tif
4   3056.809463 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170219_095504.tif
1   516.9624071 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170325_095551.tif
2   720.1932533 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170325_095551.tif
3   689.6287879 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170325_095551.tif
4   4561.576329 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170325_095551.tif
1   566.2016867 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170527_095700.tif
2   812.9927101 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170527_095700.tif
3   760.4621212 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170527_095700.tif
4   5009.537164 D:/Python/Copied/selection/20170527_095700.tif
```

And I want to format it to this:

```
band1_mean  band2_mean  band3_mean  band4_mean  raster_name         id
894.343482  1159.282304 1342.291595 3056.809463 20170219_095504.tif 1
516.9624071 720.1932533 689.6287879 4561.576329 20170325_095551.tif 2
566.2016867 812.9927101 760.4621212 5009.537164 20170527_095700.tif 3
```

All 4 bands belong to one raster and therefore the values have to be all in one row. I don't know how to stack them without having and key id for every raster.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a case of `pivot`:

```
# extract the raster name:
df['raster_name'] = df.raster.str.extract('(\d+_\d+\.tif)')

# pivot
new_df = df.pivot(index='raster_name', columns='band', values='mean')

# rename the columns:
new_df.columns = [f'band{i}_mean' for i in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
                     band1_mean   band2_mean   band3_mean   band4_mean
raster_name                                                           
20170219_095504.tif  894.343482  1159.282304  1342.291595  3056.809463
20170325_095551.tif  516.962407   720.193253   689.628788  4561.576329
20170527_095700.tif  566.201687   812.992710   760.462121  5009.537164
```

You can `reset_index` on `new_df` if you want `raster_name` to be a normal column.

Comment: Thank you. So cool. I get Nan values for the first line. I think something with the format of str.extract('(\d+_\d+\.tif)') is not right.

Comment: That part extract `digits_digits.tif`. So if some file name does not follow that patterns, it returns `NaN`. You can replace that part with some other way, e.g. split by `/`.

Comment: Solved it with df['raster_name'] = df.raster_name.str.split('/').str[4] . My original path was a little bit longer. Thank you for your big help! :)

Answer (score 1):

With `df.pivot("raster", "band", "mean")` you'd get

```
band                          1            2            3            4
raster                                                                
20170219_095504.tif  894.343482  1159.282304  1342.291595  3056.809463
20170325_095551.tif  516.962407   720.193253   689.628788  4561.576329
20170527_095700.tif  566.201687   812.992710   760.462121  5009.537164
```